# How to find critical points of multidimensional function?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, self-learning

I have this function:

$$ f(x,y) = x^2 - 2xy+ 4y^3$$

I calculated the gradient without problems:

$$\nabla f(x,y) = \left(2x-2y , -2x + 12y^3\right)^T$$

This is where kind of got stuck, I know from looking at the gradient that for $(0,0)$ the gradient is $0$, so we have a critical point there but, other than that I'm lost.

I know from $ 2x-2y$ that for for the first part of the gradient to be zero $x$ has to be equal to $y$.

I dont know how to find out the other critical points.

Answer (score 4):

> I have this function: 
>   $$ f(x,y) = x^2 - 2xy+ 4y^3$$
>   I calculated the gradient without problems:
>   $$\nabla f(x,y) = \left(2x-2y , -2x \color{red}{-} 12y^\color{red}{3}\right)^T$$

Careful, you have a small sign and exponent mistake: $\left(2x-2y , -2x \color{green}{+} 12y^\color{green}{2}\right)^T$.

> I dont know how to find out the other critical points.

But you haven't found any critical points *yet*, as you only used one equation so far. Keep in mind that requiring that the gradient is equal to $(0,0)$ is equivalent to a system of **two equations**:
$$\left\{ \begin{array}{rcl}
2x-2y &=& 0 \\
-2x + 12y^2 &=& 0 \end{array}\right.
\iff \left\{ \begin{array}{rcl}
x &=& y \\
-2x + 12y^2 &=& 0 \end{array}\right.$$
Now plug $x=y$ into the second equation and solve:
$$-2x + 12x^2 = 0 \iff -2 x\left( 1 -6x \right) = 0 \iff x = \ldots$$
Since $y=x$, each solution $x$ will correspond to a critical point $(x,x)$. Can you finish?

Comment: thanks for the correction, I think i solved it now with $x = \frac{1}{6}$ and $x=0$

Comment: @zython Correct, but note that the critical points (since $y=x$) are then $(0,0)$ and $(\tfrac{1}{6},\tfrac{1}{6})$.

Comment: this way of solving this feels a little bit _strange_ is there a better way of doing this ?

Comment: @zython What exactly do you find strange about it? You need to find the points for which the gradient is the zero vector, so this will come down to solving a system of equations. You can solve the system in any way you like, but using substitution is an obvious choice here.

Comment: youre right, feels just strange that theres no direct sort of algorithm that does it for me, any advice how to speed this up ?

Comment: Do you mean the part of solving the system? I'm afraid that heavily depends on the system. There are more _algorithmic_ methods for linear systems, but the system won't be linear in general (as in this example). As is often the case, experience & exercise will increase insight and speed up calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in order to obtain the critical points of $f(x,y) = x^2 - 2xy+ 4y^3$ you have to solve 
$$\nabla f(x,y) =\left(f_x(x,y) ,f_y(x,y)\right)= \left(2x-2y , -2x + 12y^2\right)=(0,0).$$
**Note the above gradient is different from yours!**

From $2x-2y=0$ we have that $x=y$. Then plugging this one into $-2x + 12y^2=0$ we get 
$$-2x + 12x^2=2x(-1+6x)=0\implies x=0 \;\mbox{or}\;x=1/6.$$
Therefore the critical points are $(0,0)$ and $(1/6,1/6)$.

Comment: I have calculated solutions $ x = \frac{1}{6} $ and $x=0$, is that correct ?

Comment: @zython Yes, therefore the critical points are $(0,0)$ and $(1/6,1/6)$.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that you want the gradient to be the zero vector:

**Both** $2x-2y=0$ **and** $-2x-12y^3=0$

Starting with $2x-2y=0$ gives $x=y$.

Assuming that $x=y$, turns $-2x-2y^3=0$ into $-2y-12y^3=0$.

We can solve this by factorising: $-2y(1+6y^2)=0$.

Once you solve this for $y$, your corresponding $x$-value comes from knowing that $x=y$.

Note: There is only one critical point if you are working over the reals. There are three critical points if $x$ and $y$ are allowed to be complex.